# Terms and conditions radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jsp, radio-button

I got a probably very silly question, but I couldn`t find it on the website anywhere.

I am making a website for an assignment and I`m doing rather well, but I am having trouble with the Terms and conditions radio buttons.

What I have is basically 2 radio buttons, one is Agree, second is disagree. The Disagree button is pre-selected. What is supposed to happen is basically a check if the terms and conditions are agreed before continuing to the next page.

#### TERMS & CONDITIONS

I have read and understood the CQU 
[Privacy and Security Statement](http://policy.cqu.edu.au/Policy/policy_file.do?policyid=540) and agree to the use of my personal details for related activities.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="yes">Yes, I agree.
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="no" checked="checked">No, I don`t agree.<br>

<form action="endPage.jsp">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

So basically what I need is to get the user to agree to terms and conditions, otherwise give a popup window saying you have to agree with terms and conditions.

Thank you

***tl;dr** - How do I check if a certain checkbox is checked before submitting a form?*

Comment: @Teemu - what do you mean you don`t know my question? The question is, what do I need to do to make the user select the agree button before continuing?

Comment: @user2706317 The previous comment of mine was just a different way to ask you, what have you tried? Or: SO is not a free programming service...

Comment: @Teemu - I haven`t tried anything yet because I can`t find anything similar on the internet... All I could find so far is how to make someone select a radio button if non are selected, but then again it doesn`t say that it has to be any specific button, but any of the ones offered... I already have a radio button selected and I need to make the user select the agree button before I can let him continue... Hope that gives some explanation...

Comment: @user2706317 - I answered a while ago...

Comment: @Neurofluxation - Tnx m8, I tried it, but doesn`t work, I still get through every time... I`ll try the other code now..

Answer (score 3):

Standard Javascript would be *something* like this... I imagine...

```
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");
var termsChk = document.getElementById("yes");
var formFrm = document.getElementById("form");

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (termsChk.checked === true) {
        alert("Checked!");
        formFrm.submit();
    } else {
        alert("Not Checked!");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Quick Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/yrwMc/6/

With jQuery:

```
$('#submitBtn').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#yes').attr('checked') === "checked") {
        alert("Checked!");
        $('#form').submit();
    } else {
        alert("Not Checked!");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/yrwMc/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnCheckRadio()
{   
     var radYes=document.getElementById("yes"); 
     if(radYes.checked)
     {              
        return true;
     }
     else
     {
        alert("Please agree Terms and condition");
        return false;
     }
   return false;
}

</script>

<form action="endPage.jsp">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="return fnCheckRadio();" />
</form>
```

Comment: M8 I must be doing something wrong, your function makes a lot of sense but it doesn`t work for me... here is the entire code, can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: ugh, the whole code is too long... basically what I did is took your code and put it into the <head> tag...

Comment: I also tried moving the code arond to different locations, and still the same result, I always am able to click next without warning...

Comment: Perhaps this will work in conjunction with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted

Comment: @Neurofluxation - dude you rock, that worked perfectly fine, tnx a lot :)

Comment: Gracias mi amigo! - Would appreciate a tick on my answer ;)

Comment: I hate it when people register - ask a question - get an answer - leave.